# Grant permission for specific other AD users to unlock/log out user from PC

Tags: windows, permissions, user-accounts, active-directory, logout

What I'm looking to do is permission a Windows PC (ideally XP but if a later OS version is required so be it) so that a select group of users can unlock the machine, logging the current user out. This something that a Local Admin for the machine would be able to do from a locked screen, however, I'd like to avoid granting Local Admin rights to this group of users if I can.

The background here is that this machine is 80% used by one person but is treated as a 'shared machine' on days that the primary user is not around. It's usefull that everybody using the machine can carry on using their own accounts with all the personalisations that they are used to. I'd also like to avoid logging the primary user out every night. No one else in the firm has to put up with that and she does use the machine herself most of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact is that this is a well-known problem with no great solution. The basic answer is simply, "No", you cannot do it unless you make them local administrators.

The workarounds include:

1. They can turn the computer off and restart it, but who wants to wait?
2. You can make a reboot batch file (shutdown -r -f -t 00) and schedule a task at 2 am to run that nightly, but then your primary user has to log in and reopen everything daily.
3. You can prevent locking of the workstation using GP: User Configuration>Administrative Templates>System>CTRL-ALT-DEL Options>Remove Lock Computer, and enable that, but that is a security issue.
4. If you were not on a domain, you could enable "Fast User Switching".

Personally, I would just make them local admins.

Comment: Damn. I'm going to make them local admins but not tell 'em.

Comment: @Simon Needham Obviously the downside is they can install things, which is probably not a big deal, but they could possibly get viruses they might not otherwise have gotten.

Comment: It is possible to enable fast user switching in 7 (likely Vista but I don't recall) when joined to a domain.

Comment: @edusysadmin You cannot enable fast user switching on any OS in a domain.

Comment: Yes...yes you can.  I have it enabled on the domain joined Windows 7 notebook I'm typing on right now.

Comment: @edusysadmin I was indeed wrong. You can enable it on Vista and later. I enjoy answering the questions, but I also occasionally pick up clarifications on things like this that I have wrong in my mind. Thank you.

Comment: @Simon Needham See the conversation above. You may be able to enable Fast User Switching after all, but you may need to upgrade your OS.

Comment: Hey thanks guys. I think I will go down the FUS route when the machine is swapped out for a Win7. A quick Google revels some concerns that sysadmins have with FUS and roaming profiles as user's will get in the habit of logging in everywhere and never logging out. But I think it's manageable with some scripting to monitor PCs with more than one user logged in and/or some automated weekend restarting of client machines.